# Arg function algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding the Arg function. Now I know, that $\text{Log}(z)=\log(|z|)+i\text{Arg}(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. So it holds, that $\Im(\text{Log(z)})=\text{Arg}(z)$. My problem arises from solving one of complex integrals, where I ended up with the expression $$I=\text{Arg}(1+e^{it})$$ which when plotted gives me a $2\pi$-periodic odd linear function. My question is, how do I prove this? Plus, I would like to know how to generalize this problem to
$$\text{Arg}(z_0+z_1e^{it})=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you can draw a diagram and use some elementary geometry to determine the angle.

If you want to prove your conjecture rigorously, notice that $\text{Arg}$ is multi-valued. To make it into a single valued function so that we can talk about periodicity, we need to consider it as a single-valued function from its *Riemann surface* $\mathscr S$ to $\mathbb{R}$. And we should change the definition of $1+e^{it}$ wisely, so that it maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathscr S$. Finally, we can say that $\text{Arg}(1+e^{it})$ is periodic.